# Bump a Post after X Days?

Tags: support

I have created a question on Stack Overflow (obviously) that hasn't been answered yet.  Is there a way to bump the question so that more people will see it?  There hasn't been any activity on the post for at least three days, and I don't want to ask the exact same question on another post.

It's not that my question hasn't had any responses, it's that I haven't gotten any responses after X amount of days.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are actually two ways to do this:

1. Edit your question with improvements (grammatical, content, clarifying things). This will bump up your question in the *active* tab.
2. Put a [Bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on your question. This will bump up your question in the *featured* tab.

Comment: +1 Straight to the point.  I would accept right now but I have to wait 9 more minutes. D:

Comment: Does [Community](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile) bump questions on SO?

Comment: @rene Ah, thanks. The 1st point actually clearly states it does :-). The OP asked what they can do themselves to bump it up as far I understood.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. I recall seeing somewhere that question bumping on SO was disabled but I can't find a reference, so I kind of hoped you knew ... ;)

Comment: Found a reference for the bumping rules: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/158100 so that doesn't apply here.